# Smooth Tween Font Size

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two functions that tween my data labels. The first is called `.on(mouseenter,...`  and the second is called `.on(mouseout,...`. The first function makes the data label font size bigger, and the second is supposed to return it to normal size. Both are done with `.transition()` and `.duration(500)`.

```
function text_event(id) {
  d3.selectAll(".data_label")
    .filter(function (d) {
      return (d.id == id);
    })
      .transition()
      .styleTween('font', function() {return d3.interpolate('12px Calibri', '20px Calibri' )
      .duration(500);
}

function text_event2(id) {
  d3.selectAll(".data_label")
    .filter(function (d) {
      return (d.id == id);
    })
      .transition()
      .styleTween('font', function() {return d3.interpolate('20px Calibri', '12px Calibri' )
      .duration(500);
}
```

The issue is that if you mouse in and out fast enough, the second function will actually make the font big again. Instead of starting the transition all the way at 20px, like it is currently, does d3 have a means of starting the transition back to normal size based on where the font size already is in the transition?

Comment: can you try `d3.selectAll().transition().attr('font-size', '12px').duration(500).transition().attr('font-size', '20px').duration(500);` ?

Comment: That produced an unexpected result. When I hover over the text for the first time, the text shoots to 20px instantly, which is not what I wanted. However, oddly enough, after that the transition behavior is what I wanted.  Is there any explanation about what could be causing the first function call to behave in such a way?

Comment: have you done similar change for initial state( make it 12 ) , mouse out ( move 20 to 12 ) and mouse enter ( move 12 to 20 ) ?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean by initial state. My mouse event looks like this: `.on('mouseenter', function(d) {text_event(d.id);})` I'm not sure what you want me to change. I'd be happy to award you the answer if you know how to fix the jumpy behavior on the first mouse hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing the interpolator you have to set the actual value as the starting value instead of using the static end values `12px` or `20px`. This can easily be done by retrieving the value using `d3.select(this).style("font")`:

```
return d3.interpolate(d3.select(this).style("font"), '20px Calibri' )
```

Have a look at this working example:

```js
d3.selectAll("text")
  .on("mouseenter", text_event)
  .on("mouseleave", text_event2);
  
function text_event() {
  d3.selectAll(".data_label")
    .transition()
      .styleTween('font', function() {
        return d3.interpolate(d3.select(this).style("font"), '20px Calibri' )
      })
      .duration(500);
}

function text_event2() {
  d3.selectAll(".data_label")
    .transition()
      .styleTween('font', function() {
        return d3.interpolate(d3.select(this).style("font"), '12px Calibri' )
      })
      .duration(500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<svg>
  <text x="100" y="100" class="data_label" style="font: 12px Calibri;">Test</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's interesting that `.attr('font')` doesn't work, but `.style('font')` does. Cool solution, thank you!

Comment: If you had first set the value as an attribute, i.e. `<text font="...">` it would be accessible by `.attr()`. But, because it was set as a style, it is now only accessible by `.style()`. Thinking about it this way, it becomes apparent and seems consistent, though.